# What is a pattern correlation coefficient?

Tags: correlation

I am asked to compute for pattern correlation.

The pattern correlation is the Pearson product-moment coefficient of linear correlation between two variables that are respectively the values of the same variables at corresponding locations on two different maps. https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Contributed/pattern_cor.shtml

I have a Pearson correlation map but I would like to compute for the pattern correlation. Can you help me compute for pattern correlation instead of Pearson correlation?

Comment: This is purely a computing problem.  Moreover, your link provides an explicit solution: it directs readers to software that will do the job.

Comment: For those who are looking for the formula of pattern correlation, this is a good start. https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4441/10/1/28